# MediaStore Uri for External?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

As a MediaStore newbie's, I dunno what's wrong with this uri:

```
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
```

Those uri's keeps returns to zero.

My example codes:

```
String file = null;
String sortBy = "";
if (filterSort == "time") {
    sortBy = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED;
} else if (filterSort == "size") {
    sortBy = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE;
}
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), projection, null, null, sortBy + "DESC");
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        file = cursor.getString(0);
        states.add(file);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Trying to solve with
`Uri.parse` worked but did not apply sorting filter's. Back with
`MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")` , it keeps giving me this via Exception on Android 8.1 devices:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
no such column: date_modifiedDESC (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _data FROM files WHERE ( invalid=0) ORDER BY date_modifiedDESC
```

Is there any **way** to solve/change/do?

Comment: If the uri is null then do not use it. .getContentUri() is only for modern Android devices. Android Studio will tell you and probably did already

Comment: Exception that I wrote was from Android 8.1 devices. when I'm tried running the projects on Android 11, it has same problem, but different Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Nor sure what blackapps is referring to as he does not address the question in any way.

There are a number of uris, depending what you want to extract.
for example:

```
public Uri get_audio_media_uri(){
    Uri uri_to_use = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    return uri_to_use;
}
```

or for artists;

```
public Uri get_audio_artist_uri(){
    Uri uri_to_use = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    return uri_to_use;
}
```

the part "date_modifiedDESC" is what causes the issue as it requires a space "date_modified DESC"

[image: structure (part) of files table]

I suggest you amend your projection, for example

```
String projection[];
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    //no _DATA column in Q
    projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
    };
} else {
    projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
    };
}
```

instead of `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED;`

Comment: It worked but sorting by date modified not applied

Comment: Finally, one more tip. If a query returns an error you  often are unaware so by generating a deliberate error you can often see what the issue is. I usually do this by adding an invalid column eg "a", much in the same way of your original issue